# Usage of Snapshotlistener on a Firestore .addDocument which adds its own ID to a document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a new document with this and add also the document id to it:

```
func createGroup(userUid: String, groupName: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let dic = ["groupName": groupName, "userUid": userUid, "timeStamp": timeStamp] as [String : Any]
     
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    
    ref = db.collection("groups").addDocument(data: dic) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            onError()
        } else {
            let docId = ref!.documentID
            print("data setted")
            ref?.setData(["groupId": docId], merge: true)
            onSuccess()
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have a Snapshotlistener like this to add the created data to a table view:

```
func getGroupsForAUser(userUid: String, onSuccess: @escaping (GroupsModel) -> Void, onError: @escaping () -> Void, onEmpty: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("groups").whereField("userUid", isEqualTo: userUid).order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, err) in
        if err != nil {
            onError()
        } else {
            snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach { (diff) in
                if (diff.type == .added) {
                    let dic = diff.document.data()
                    print(GroupsModel(dictionary: dic).groupId)
                    print(GroupsModel(dictionary: dic).groupName)
                    let group = GroupsModel(dictionary: dic)
                    onSuccess(group)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

The Problem: The snapshotlistener fires before "ref?.setData(...)" and I am missing some important information about my newly created data.

How can I modify the snapshotlistener that it will be triggered after "setData" and not on my "addDocument" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the random ID of a new document generated on the client before you set the data on it by calling [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/CollectionReference#document) with no arguments:

```
let ref = db.collection("groups").document()
let id = ref.documentID
```

You now have a reference to a document that doesn't yet exist, but you know it's ID. You can use that to add the ID into the document when you create it:

```
ref.setData([
    "groupId": id,
    // ...
])
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) for more details.